# Enabling a disabled form button after submit & browser back button

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

Submit button is disabled using '**button.prop**' during form submission. If user navigates back to the form with the browser back button, the submit button remains disabled.

How to have it re-enabled?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit-form').validate();
$('#submit-form').on('submit', function (e) { 
    var button = $('#submit-btn'); 
    var c37=$('#c37').val(); 
    var c42=$('#c42').val(); 
    var c48=$('#c48').val(); 
    var c53=$('#c53').val(); 
    var c1=$('#c1').val(); 
    var c2=$('#c2').val(); 
    if(c37=="" || c42=="" || c42=="" || c48=="" || c53=="" || c1=="" ||c2==""){
            button.prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
            button.prop('disabled', true); 
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: If all fields contain some value, then your button **gets disabled**. You can put at the end of the code `button.prop('disabled', false)` independiently its result always avaliable. 
_Advice_: Use `===` instead of `==` in the _if_ sentence.

Comment: try this -> `$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
 button.prop("disabled", false);
});`

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a browser specific issue -- out of those tested, the following browsers re-enabled the submit button automatically:

- Microsoft Edge 20
- Google Chrome 53
- Opera 40
- Mobile Google Chrome (iOS) 45

Adding the following code to the bottom of the form, before the closing 
'body' tag -- solved the problem at least for these tested browsers:

**Mozilla Firefox 44**

```
window.onunload = function(){};
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit-btn').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

**Safari 9.1.3**

**Mobile Safari (iOS 8.3)**

**Mobile Firefox 5.3**

**Internet Explorer 11**

```
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
if (event.persisted) {
window.location.reload() 
}
};
```

Comment: It's true that the issue is browser specific. But the firefox fix didn't seem to work (version 60.0).

Answer (score 0):

"If all fields contain some value, then your button gets disabled" thats true - switch them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit-form').validate();
    $('#submit-form').on('submit', function (e) { 
        var button = $('#submit-btn'); 
        var c37=$('#c37').val(); 
        var c42=$('#c42').val(); 
        var c48=$('#c48').val(); 
        var c53=$('#c53').val(); 
        var c1=$('#c1').val(); 
        var c2=$('#c2').val(); 
        if(c37=="" || c42=="" || c42=="" || c48=="" || c53=="" || c1=="" ||c2==""){
      button.prop('disabled', true);   // switched places          

        } else {
      button.prop("disabled", false); 
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: the button needs to be disabled when "all fields contain some value".